# Theme taxonomy term page with template override

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I know this is far from duplicate but im a bit stupid. 
I am trying to theme the terms page for each term for a specific vocabulary i created. 
I 've used path auto when i was creating the terms so i have a specific path for each vocabulary term.

My website is using a subtheme that i created by copying and pasting the main theme which is ninesixty. So i have tried creating a new template for taxonomy terms like taxonomy-term--12.tpl.php added my html code and unfortunately the template wasnt overridden.
I have also tried to override the template using the template.php file with no luck.
 I dont want to use any module so any clear answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below filename structure to create a taxonomy term template:

```
taxonomy-term--[vocabulary-machine-name|tid].tpl.php
```

Comment: so if i have vocabulary machine name as company_news_categories and term id 8 that will be taxonomy-term--company_news_categories8.tpl.php ?

Comment: No, because `|` means "or". Use `taxonomy-term--company_news_categories.tpl.php` to format all terms of your vocabulary, _or_ use `taxonomy-term--8.tpl.php` to format only term 8.

Term IDs are unique across all vocabularies, so there is no need to have both pieces in the filenames.